# How to design a circuit for switching between two power sources for two loads, only one power source having a resistor for each load?

Tags: circuit-design

On my board I have an internal power supply 12V. I also have 2 loads, each of them require their own resistor when connected to the internal power supply.
However, now I want to add an external power supply and a switch between the two power supplies.

The problem arises because I need two separate resistors for the two loads, and they must be used only when internal 12V power supply is selected, and with the external one the load must be connected directly.

Here is how it looks now:
[image]

Here is how I want it to look, except that I need two separate resistors for each load:
[image]

Do you have any ideas how to design such a circuit? How is it usually implemented?

Thanks!

Comment: Your diagrams are incorrect electrically and won't work.

Comment: @Andyaka, oh, yeah, do you mean the wrong directorion of LEDs? I'll fix it now

Comment: What is the purpose of the resistors, and why don't you require them with the external supply?  Are the loads really just LEDs?

Comment: I would say to use a constant current resistor but there aren't enough details to make it an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe use a DPDT switch like this: -

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYvZxI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm showing the loads as a box rather than an LED because, it's not good practice to put LEDs in parallel unless you know what you are doing.